# Why doesn't while (*s++=*t++); work for me?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, strcpy

I came across this function on a blog and I found it really cool. I understand how it works conceptually since C++ was my first language.

However, when I tried actually writing it out in a program of mine, it doesn't seem to work. I've googled all over but I've only found explanations as to how it works so I've been really stumped.

Instead of copying the NULL char[5] (which should evaluate to false, copy nothing and break the loop), it gives two **compilation** errors, saying that "I can't increment value of **type** char[6]" (out-of-bounds error for both arrays).

Why doesn't my loop break at char[5]?

I'm guessing it's something to do with the subtleties of char and string, I tried initialising strings instead with cstring included, that didn't work either, the similar error of "cannot increment type string" shows up.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
     char s[] = "hello";
     char t[] = "house";
     while (*s++ = *t++);
     cout << s;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this your real code? It shouldn't compile.

Comment: @T.C.: I guess that's what "it gives two errors" means.  And both errors give the type of `s` and `t`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Heh, I thought it's some sanitizer, with the "out-of-bounds" and "why doesn't my loop break" and all. That's why it's important to post the compiler errors verbatim...

Comment: @T.C. Sorry, first time posting, will keep in mind

Comment: The actual error message seems to [read](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8ac807a2611a3e8) "cannot increment value of **type** 'char [6]'". The word "type" is important.

Comment: The great irony of this code is that if you used a plain pointer instead of the array notation it would work, and at runtime you'd be fighting your operating system's safety checks trying to overwrite readonly memory. Talk about a lose-lose.

Comment: @Blindy By using a plain pointer you mean assigning "hello" to a char* s for example? But that would be a pointer to a string literal and wouldn't work because you can't modify a string literal...right?

Comment: Depending on your compiler and its settings that may just be a warning at compile-time, which was his point (it'd still crash at runtime on most operating systems, as he mentioned).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't increment an array. What would that even mean?

Try this:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   char s[] = "hello";
   char t[] = "house";

   char *ss = s;
   char *tt = t;
   while (*ss++ = *tt++);

   cout << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: Won't this modified code case UB by writing to an array that's specified by a string literal?

Comment: @templatetypedef: The string literal is copied to the array. The problem comes when you initialize (or just assign) a pointer to a string literal, and try to modify it.

Comment: Isn't an array similar to a pointer though?
Like s[1] is equivalent to *(s+1)?

And why use ss? Don't ss and s point to the same memory location anyway? (first char of s)

Comment: @Coolshanth: arrays decay to pointer values.  So `[]` works the same on both.  But the resulting pointer value is an expression, not an lvalue, so you can't *modify* it with `++`.

Comment: @Coolshanth arrays are not pointers. `s` is an array, and it *decays* to a pointer to its first element when we assign it to `ss`.

Comment: @BenVoigt On a side note, could you clarify what you mean by "[] works same on both"? I don't think ss[2] for example would be valid, I tried cout on it, didn't work.

Comment: @Coolshanth: Try that earlier, above the loop.

Comment: @Coolshanth `ss[2]` is valid. If you try it before `ss` is incremented, it will give you the third character in the string. (Once `ss` is incremented to the end, `ss[2]` is off the end of the array.) In most cases, `a[b]` is the same as `*(a+b)`.

Comment: I went through the while loop on paper, realised ss corresponds to one memory location after the NULL char. 
So to achieve my intended effect of printing the 3rd char of s using ss after assignment, ss[-4] does the trick. I'll go out on a limb and assume that's bad programming practice. Anyway, thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score -2):

The line " while (*ss++ = *tt++) " is always going to be true, because = is the assignment operator. You probably want " while (*ss++ == *tt"")", which compares equality.

Comment: No, it will be false if `*tt == '\0'`. And that's the point, because the purpose is to copy until that particular character (the null terminator) is found.

Comment: nope, like Benjamin aluded to, the assignment operator returns the assigned value. Which let's you do stuff like `a=b=c;`